# Using R to generate a time series of averages from a very large dataset without using for loops

Tags: r, time-series

I am working with a large dataset of patent data. Each row is an individual patent, and columns contain information including application year and number of citations in the patent.

```
> head(p)
  allcites appyear asscode assgnum cat cat_ocl  cclass country ddate gday gmonth
1        6    1974       2       1   6       6 2/161.4      US          6      1
2        0    1974       2       1   6       6    5/11      US          6      1
3       20    1975       2       1   6       6   5/430      US          6      1
4        4    1974       1      NA   5    <NA> 114/354                  6      1
5        1    1975       1      NA   6       6 12/142S                  6      1
6        3    1972       2       1   6       6 15/53.4      US          6      1
  gyear hjtwt       icl icl_class icl_maingroup iclnum nclaims nclass nclass_ocl
1  1976     1 A41D 1900      A41D            19      1       4      2          2
2  1976     1 A47D  701      A47D             7      1       3      5          5
3  1976     1 A47D  702      A47D             7      1      24      5          5
4  1976     1 B63B  708      B63B             7      1       7    114          9
5  1976     1 A43D  900      A43D             9      1       9     12         12
6  1976     1 B60S  304      B60S             3      1      12     15         15
   patent   pdpass state status subcat subcat_ocl subclass subclass1 subclass1_ocl
1 3930271 10030271    IL            63         63    161.4     161.4           161
2 3930272 10156902    PA            65         65     11.0        11            11
3 3930273 10112031    MO            65         65    430.0       430           331
4 3930274       NA    CA            55         NA    354.0       354             2
5 3930275       NA    NJ            63         63       NA      142S           142
6 3930276 10030276    IL            69         69     53.4      53.4            53
  subclass_ocl term_extension uspto_assignee      gdate
1          161              0         251415 1976-01-06
2           11              0         246000 1976-01-06
3          331              0          10490 1976-01-06
4            2              0              0 1976-01-06
5          142              0              0 1976-01-06
6           53              0         243840 1976-01-06
```

I am attempting to create a new data frame which contains the mean number of citations (`allcites`) per application year (`appyear`), separated by category (`cat`), for patents from 1970 to 2006 (the data goes all the way back to 1901). I did this successfully, but I feel like my solution is somewhat ad hoc and does not take advantage of the specific capabilities of R. Here is my solution

```
#citations by category
citescat <- data.frame("chem"=integer(37),
                       "comp"=integer(37),
                       "drugs"=integer(37),
                       "ee"=integer(37),
                       "mech"=integer(37),
                       "other"=integer(37),
                       "year"=1970:2006
                       )
for (i in 1:37) {
  for (j in 1:6) {
    citescat[i,j] <- mean(p$allcites[p$appyear==(i+1969) & p$cat==j], na.rm=TRUE)
  }
}
```

I am wondering if there is a simple way to do this without using the nested for loops which would make it easy to make small tweaks to it. It is hard for me to pin down exactly what I am looking for other than this, but my code just looks ugly to me and I suspect that there are better ways to do this in R.

Comment: I'm sure someone will answer this, and when they do it will use either the **plyr** or **data.table** package. You will want to Google both of those and read some intros. It will pay dividends.

Comment: @joran: What about the `aggregate` function? It gets no love...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joran is right - here's a `plyr` solution. Without your dataset in a usable form it's hard to show you exactly, but here it is in a simplified dataset:

```
p <- data.frame(allcites = sample(1:20, 20), appyear = 1974:1975, pcat = rep(1:4, each = 5))

#First calculate the means of each group
cites <- ddply(p, .(appyear, pcat), summarise, meancites = mean(allcites, na.rm = T))

#This gives us the data in long form
#   appyear pcat meancites
# 1    1974    1 14.666667
# 2    1974    2  9.500000
# 3    1974    3 10.000000
# 4    1974    4 10.500000
# 5    1975    1 16.000000
# 6    1975    2  4.000000
# 7    1975    3 12.000000
# 8    1975    4  9.333333

#Now use dcast to get it in wide form (which I think your for loop was doing):
citescat <- dcast(cites, appyear ~ pcat)
#   appyear        1   2  3         4
# 1    1974 14.66667 9.5 10 10.500000
# 2    1975 16.00000 4.0 12  9.333333
```

Hopefully you can see how to adapt that to your specific data.

Comment: this worked perfectly! Thanks very much, I'm working on trying to get a handle on what the `plyr` and `reshape2` packages do.